# How do I know, what day of week is a date

Tags: r

I've got the following problem: I have the daily stock exchange rates of a certain share stored in a vector with the belonging date(from 2015 to 2017).

I need to extract the last exchange rate of every week.

This means I need to know what weekday corresponds to every date and store those rates in a vector (or delete the other rows from the existing vector). I did this by using 'wday' (from lubridate) and then did the following:

```
 vector<-stochexchangerate
 weekdays<-wday(stockexchangerate)   ## length =35; monday=2,   
 tuesday=3,..

  for(i in 1:10){
       if(weekdays[i]<6){
           vector<-vector[-c(i)]
              }
          }
```

But this only has the consequence, that some "random" rows are deleted and if I run this code 6 times, there is only 1 row left although there were some values which were taken on friday. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, using `lubridate` was a good insight. I would extract the day of the week using `lubridate::wday` and argument `label = TRUE` and filter that column.

Assuming that you have a dataframe with 2 columns (one for the dates and, one for the value of rates) you can do:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

# DATA
#> df <-  tibble(date = mdy("02/15/1980") + 1:300,
#>               value = 1:300)

df %>% 
  mutate(day = wday(date, label = TRUE)) %>% 
  filter(day == "Fri")

#> # A tibble: 42 x 3
#>    date       value day  
#>    <date>     <int> <ord>
#>  1 1980-02-22     7 Fri  
#>  2 1980-02-29    14 Fri  
#>  3 1980-03-07    21 Fri  
#>  4 1980-03-14    28 Fri  
#>  5 1980-03-21    35 Fri  
#>  6 1980-03-28    42 Fri  
#>  7 1980-04-04    49 Fri  
#>  8 1980-04-11    56 Fri  
#>  9 1980-04-18    63 Fri  
#> 10 1980-04-25    70 Fri  
#> # … with 32 more rows
```

Comment: The problem is, that the stock returns with the corresponding date are stored in a matrix with 35 rows and 1(!) column.

Comment: I see. Can you please update the post with info regarding the matrix? Use `dput(your_matrix)` . With a better idea of your data I will be able to provide a more tailored solution